# Searching for Array Key in $_POST, PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add commenting like StackOverflow and Facebook uses to a site I'm building. Basically, each parent post will have its own child comments. I plan to implement the front-end with jQuery Ajax but I'm struggling with how to best tackle the PHP back-end.

Since having the same name and ID for each form field would cause validation errors (and then some, probably), I added the parent post's ID to each form field. Fields that will be passed are commentID, commentBody, commentAuthor - with the ID added they will be `commentTitle-12`, etc.

Since the `$_POST` array_key will be different each time a new post is processed, I need to trim off the `-12` (or whatever the ID may be) from the `$_POST` key, leaving just commentTitle, commentBody, etc. and its associated value.

Example

```
$_POST['commentTitle-12']; //how it would be received after submission
$_POST['commentTitle']; //this is what I am aiming for
```

Many thanks

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to CFreak-

```
//Basic example, not actual script
<?php
if (array_key_exists("send", $_POST)) {
    $title = $_POST['title'][0];
    $body = $_POST['body'][0];
    echo $title . ', ' . $body;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form name="test" id="test" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="title[]"/>
<input type="text" name="body[]"/>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 2**
Oops, kind of forgot the whole point of it - unique names (although it's been established that 1) this isn't really necessary and 2) probably better, for this application, to do this using jQuery instead)

```
//Basic example, not actual script
    <?php
    if (array_key_exists("send", $_POST)) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'][$id];
        $body = $_POST['body'][$id];
        echo $title . ', ' . $body;
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form name="test" id="test" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="title[<?php echo $row['id'];?>]"/>
    <input type="text" name="body[<?php echo $row['id'];?>]"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; //the ID?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should only ever be posting one comment back at a time so I think you may be approaching the problem the wrong way.  The name is used as the key for the post array and having elements with the same name is fine.  so when somebody submits a comment, just get the parent id and pass it as an extra param in the ajax post.

Comment: You're absolutely right. In this particular case, knowing that the sole user of this page will have Javascript enabled, I am going to use only jQuery to accomplish this. However, for future cases where that may not be the case, I'd like to figure out how to best handle this with PHP.. but again, you're right. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a little trick to get arrays or even multi-dimensional arrays out of an HTML form. In the HTML name your field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="commentTitle[12]" value="(whatever default value)" />
```

(you can use variables or whatever to put in the "12" if that's what you're doing, the key is the [ ] brackets.

Then in PHP you'll get:

```
$_POST['commentTitle'][12]
```

You could then just loop through the comments and grabbing each by the index ID.

You can also just leave it as empty square brackets in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="commentTitle[]" value="(whatever default value)" />
```

That will just make it an indexed array starting at 0, if you don't care what the actual ID value is.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, we're on to something here.. however, how would I then pull the value from the form's `value` attribute? Thanks :)

Comment: $commentTitle = $_POST['commentTitle'][12]; Does that make sense? If not I can edit my answer to provide a more complete example.

Comment: Or at least I think I'm on the right path (update 2) -- correct?

Comment: That looks fine. However if you're only sending one at a time (my confusion, I thought the point was you were sending more than one), why not just pass an extra HTML parameter with the ID? Also I don't understand your jQuery comment. If you add jQuery it works basically the same way on the backend

Comment: Initially I thought I might run into errors if I had many form fields of the same name on the same page - apparently this is not the case..

Comment: You shouldn't run into errors as long as the fields with the same name are in separate forms :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to iterate through `$_POST` and search for matching keys:

```
function extract_vars_from_post($arr) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        // $key looks like asdasd-12
        if (preg_match('/([a-z]+)-\d+/', $key, $match)) {
            $result[$match[1]] = $val;
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Didn't test the code, though